# Однородные деепричастные обороты

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

> Его товарищ согнулся, поставив локти, и, подпирая скулы ладонями.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь дееприч. об. не однородны, потому что отвечают на разные вопросы?
"поставив локти"- что сделав?
"подпирая скулы"- что делая?
Или здесь другое объяснение для запятых?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:  (1) **Его товарищ согнулся, поставив локти (на стол?) и подпирая скулы ладонями.**

Сравним (1) с предложением (2) *Его товарищ согнулся, поставив локти (на стол?) и подперев скулы ладонями.*

Содержание предложения не изменилось, но есть изменение в  грамматике.

В предложении (2) мы имеем последовательность действий, что соответствует однородным обстоятельствам времени.

В предложении (1) обстоятельства также однородны, но теперь они обозначают позу и являются обстоятельствами образа действия.

Таким образом, **однородность обстоятельств, выраженных деепричастиями, определяется не по их форме, а по смыслу.** Обстоятельства, выраженных деепричастиями, могут  находиться в однородных отношениях даже с наречиями, то есть с другими частями речи.

Answer (score 1):

Оба оборота — обстоятельства образа действия, поэтому они одонородны и **запятая между ними не нужна**, тем более две запятые. "Поставив локти" требует пояснения, куда. Но возможно, это и так ясно из контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Однородность глаголов (а деепричастие - глагольная форма) не зависит ни от вида, ни от времени. *Маша пришла из школы и делает уроки*.

> Его товарищ согнулся, поставив локти, И, подпирая скулы ладонями.

Такой "спотыкач" из запятых должен всегда настораживать.

Comment: И? (Каков вердикт?)

Comment: Ну ясно же... Специально придумал похожий пример, где отсутствие запятой между однородными членами сомнений не вызывает. А вот ваш аргумент (оба оборота — обстоятельства образа действия, *поэтому* они однородны) неверен.

Comment: Краткость, она, конечно, сестра таланта, но не всегда она сама талантлива . Лучше явно писать: запятые не нужны; ваш агрумент неверен, потому что...., однородность глаголов не зависит ни от вида, ни от времени, а зависит от...

Comment: Многословием здесь знамениты многие, надо же хоть чем-нибудь отличаться... То, что объясняется просто, надо объяснять просто. Пусть я в трех случаях из ста окажусь верхоглядом.